# Spark-submit with properties file for python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to load spark configuration through the properties file using the following command in Spark 2.4.0.

`spark-submit --properties-file props.conf sample.py`

It gives the following error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Dynamic allocation of executors requires the external shuffle service. You may enable this through spark.shuffle.service.enabled.
```

The `props.conf` file has this

```
spark.master    yarn
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.authenticate  true
spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.driver.memory 4g
spark.driver.memoryOverhead 2048
spark.executor.memory   2g
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   2048
```

Now, when I try to run the same by adding all arguments to the command itself, it works fine.

```
spark2-submit \
--conf spark.master=yarn \
--conf spark.submit.deployMode=client \
--conf spark.authenticate=true \
--conf spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.driver.memory=4g \
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 \
sample.py
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think spark supports `--properties-file`, one workaround is making the change on `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`, spark will auto load it.

You can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#loading-configuration-from-a-file

Comment: It seems to be supported here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/699b9a5ff06c9640ff25ddd4dd47084781b556b6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L534